# Python 2.7 pptx textframe autofit size

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-pptx

I need to fit a text frame to the exact size to be centered above the center of an image, the issue is that when i give it a width and a left value, when the text does not fill it, it's getting smaller, same when it's smaller than the text demands,

I tried to use [auto fit](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/txt-autofit-text.html) but this is not what i need

And tried to change the width, height values but it behaves according to the actual text size.

I need some way to center the text box around a certain left value for it to be around the middle of the slide.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A reliable way to center text like this is to make the text box the same width as the picture (and aligned with it), and then set the text alignment (justification) of the text paragraph to center.

The resulting text box is often wider than strictly necessary to show the text, but PowerPoint does the alignment for you and very reliably.

Comment: and what happens if the text is wider than the given width? how can i tell it to auto fit the text to the given size?

Comment: @captainshai Were you thinking reduce the font size or wrap the text?

Comment: I need this to fit to a certain size without knowing nothing of the amont of text... it changes every run. It is not fisible to make the font smaller. I will never know how small it needs to be...

Comment: @captainshai How would you accomplish this by hand using PowerPoint? That usually gives a pretty good idea of where to start. If you can't accomplish it with the PowerPoint UI, you most likely won't be able to do it with `python-pptx` either :)